# ehcache server synchronization in spring-boot

Tags: spring-boot, ehcache

I am a beginner developer who wants to use ehcache

I wanted to synchronize the cache on multiple servers with ehcache

But it blocked in which phenomena close as soon as the connection to the server.

We tried to find and fix this, but we could not fix it.

I'd appreciate it if you let me know what you need to fix.

ehcache.xml

```
<ehcache>
    <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir">

    <cacheManagerPeerProviderFactory 
        class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerProviderFactory" 
        properties="peerDiscovery=automatic, multicastGroupAddress=230.0.0.1,
        multicastGroupPort=28899, timeToLive=32"/> 

    <cacheManagerPeerListenerFactory
        class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerListenerFactory"
        properties="hostName=localhost, port=28899, 
        socketTimeoutMillis=2000"/>

    <cache 
        name="sessionInfoCache"
        maxElementsInMemory="10000" 
        eternal="false" 
        timeToIdleSeconds="600" 
        timeToLiveSeconds="1200" 
        overflowToDisk="false"> 

        <cacheEventListenerFactory 
            class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheReplicatorFactory" 
            properties="replicateAsynchronously=true, replicatePuts=true,       
            replicateUpdates=true, 
            replicateUpdatesViaCopy=false, replicateRemovals=true ">
        </cacheEventListenerFactory> 
        <bootstrapCacheLoaderFactory 
            class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIBootstrapCacheLoaderFactory"
            properties="bootstrapAsynchronously=true,                          
            maximumChunkSizeBytes=5000000"/>

    </cache> 

    <cache 
        name="resourceInfoCache"
        maxElementsInMemory="10000" 
        eternal="false" 
        timeToIdleSeconds="600" 
        timeToLiveSeconds="1200" 
        overflowToDisk="false"> 

        <cacheEventListenerFactory 
            class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheReplicatorFactory" 
            properties="replicateAsynchronously=true, replicatePuts=true,             
            replicateUpdates=true, 
            replicateUpdatesViaCopy=false, replicateRemovals=true ">
        </cacheEventListenerFactory>
        <bootstrapCacheLoaderFactory 
            class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIBootstrapCacheLoaderFactory" 
            properties="bootstrapAsynchronously=true,            
            maximumChunkSizeBytes=5000000"/>

    </cache> 


</ehcache>
```

class that uses ehcache

```
@Autowired
private EhCacheCacheManager ehCacheManager;


public void setServerResourceInfoCache(ResourceInfo resourceInfo) {
    Cache resourceInfoCache = ehCacheManager.getCache("resourceInfoCache");
    resourceInfoCache.put(resourceInfo.getServerId(), resourceInfo);
}

public void removeServerResourceInfoCache(ResourceInfo resourceInfo) {
    Cache resourceInfoCache = ehCacheManager.getCache("resourceInfoCache");
    resourceInfoCache.evict(resourceInfo.getServerId());
} 

public void getResourceInfoCache() {

    Cache resourceInfoCache = ehCacheManager.getCache("resourceInfoCache");
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<String> cacheKeyList = ehCacheManager.getCacheManager().getCache("resourceInfoCache").getKeys();

    System.out.println();
    if(cacheKeyList!=null && cacheKeyList.size()>0){
        for (String keyString : cacheKeyList) {
            System.out.println(keyString + " - " +resourceInfoCache.get(keyString).get().toString());
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("cacheKeyList = 0");
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("---------------------------------------");

}
```

}